# Django to share login session with Jasperserver

Tags: python, django, jasperserver

I have a Django application and I use Jasperserver to generate reports. Can I somehow share the login session from Django to jasperserver to eliminate login step in jasperserver ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could, for example, in an iframe, do a post to j_spring_security_check to authenticate the user, that way when you redirect him to the login page, the user would be authenticated

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately we decided to ditch jasperserver, so I can't test your method.

Answer (score 0):

A Easy Way for this... is this=> a Python Rest Client for Jasper Report Server

http://www.redrails.com.br/2013/03/07/python-client-para-rest-api-do-jasper-report-server/